# Find Bezout's identity coefficients for $18 + \sqrt{-19}$, $18 - \sqrt{-19}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$

Tags: number-theory

I want to find coefficients $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ such that $a(18 + \sqrt{-19}) + b(18 - \sqrt{-19}) = 1$ (I know that these elements are coprime in  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$).

At first I thought of the extended euclidean algorithm, but then I remembered that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is not an Euclidean domain, it's not even a unique factorization domain.

Setting $a = b = 1$ gives $a(18 + \sqrt{-19}) + b(18 - \sqrt{-19}) = 36$, but this does not help either because 36 is not a unit.

Is there a systematic way to go about this, or just guesswork?

Comment: Why should $(18+\sqrt{-19},18-\sqrt{-19})$ be principal?

Comment: Considering the coefficients to be $a + b\sqrt{-19}$ and $c + d\sqrt{-19}$ and then solving, where does that lead? I don't know if it helps but it might.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't expected to solve this in the integral closure $\Bbb{Z}[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2]$? After all, that ring is a PID :-)

Comment: @user10354138  Because the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-19})$ is $1$.

Comment: @Piquito True, but my guess is that user10354138 was worried about the problem not being phrased using the full ring of integers.

Comment: @Piquito I think you are confusing $\mathfrak{o}\cap\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-19}]=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2]$ with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$.

Comment: Anyway, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is not a Bezout domain.

Comment: The method in the answer in the dupe also works here (same as in Jyrki's answer).

Comment: As for algorithms for computing the gcd Bezout equation we can methods similar to Hurwitz's general division algorithm, e.g. see Section 2 (Applications) in Lemmmermeyer's [An application of the Dedekind-Hasse criterion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1147.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z_1=18+\sqrt{-19}$, $z_2=18-\sqrt{-19}$. We have
$$z_1+z_2=36$$
as well as
$$
z_1z_2=343.
$$
We have $\gcd(36,343)=1$, and a run of Euclid shows that
$$1=162\cdot 36-17\cdot343.$$

Therefore
$$
1=162(z_1+z_2)-17z_1z_2=(162-17z_2)z_1+162z_2.
$$

Comment: I first used the prime factors, but that lead to a more complicate solution. See the edit history if you are reaaaally interested :-)

Comment: I have no idea how generally this method works and even yields an answer in a non-maximal order of algebraic integers?

Comment: Probably some luck that "a run of Euclid" does succeed? That is, at least with a naive "norm", it could fail, despite the (correct) ring being a PID, but not norm-Euclidean?

Comment: I forgot that here the integral closure, while a PID, is not norm-Euclidean. Thanks for the reminder @paulgarrett. If you recall related more general results, please share. I guess I was lucky.

Comment: I capitalized on the fact that here the trace and the norm had no common factors. Of course it was essential that the two numbers happened to be each others conjugates.